# RxJs: How to return an Observable<T> from an Observable<T[]>?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm calling a web service that returns a List.  I want to return one item from that List, in a method.  Essentially, when some function requests an instance of CollectorIssueBase, I want to retrieve ALL of them, cache them and return the one requested.  But I can't figure out how to do it.
Here's my code:

```
  public getByID(collectorID: string, id: string): Observable<CollectorIssueBase> {
    return this.getAllMinimized(collectorID).pipe(
        single(items => {
            var item = items.find(i => i.ID == id);
            return item;
          })
      );
  }
```

1. The compiler keeps complaining that "Argument of type 'CollectorIssueValue[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CollectorIssueValue' which tells me right off the bat that I'm still returning an Array.
2. The value returned to the subscribing function is, indeed, an Array.

So what am I doing wrong?  "single" seemed like the proper operator to use...am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

single callback takes `CollectorIssueValue[]` form each observable tick. If you want to change `CollectorIssueValue[]` to `CollectorIssueValue` i suggest use filter and map. Filter will filter empty arrays, and map will transform not empty array of `CollectorIssueValue` into `CollectorIssueValue`.

e.g.:

```js
.pipe(
  filter(arr => arr.length > 0),
  map(arr => arr.find(...),
```